# Why does redirect happen before my jquery click event is fired for a html anchor element?

Tags: jquery, html, onbeforeunload, event-bubbling, event-propagation

I'm trying to trigger the OnBeforePageUnload only when the user closes the tab or browser window. When the user navigates on my website, I have a custom mechanism that will trigger a warning dialog to prevent the user from losing entered data. So every time a link on my page has been clicked, I set the a flag:

```
$('a[href]').click(function (event) {
    buttonOutsidePageClicked = false;
});
```

Then, the onbeforepageunload event is triggered. I check the value of the flag to see if I should show the built in onbeforeunload dialog or not:

```
function OnBeforeUnload(oEvent) {
if (buttonOutsidePageClicked)
    return navAwayMessage;   
}
```

This works fine for all my links on the page except for the following one:

```
 <a id="cpm_UploadLink" class="button" rel="no" href="/pages/otherPage">
    <span class="btnLeft"></span>
    <span class="btnMiddle">Click Me</span>
    <span class="btnRight"></span>
 </a>
```

These html is created by a custom web control. When i click on the link, i get redirected to the otherPage without the click event has been triggered. So i cannot set the flag and the built in onbeforeunload message is shown.

When I add an inline add the onclick attribute directly in the control like this:

```
 <a id="cpm_UploadLink" class="button" rel="no" href="/pages/otherPage"
     onclick="javascript:buttonOutsidePageClicked = false;">
        <span class="btnLeft"></span>
        <span class="btnMiddle">Click Me</span>
        <span class="btnRight"></span>
 </a>
```

Everything works fine. But that's not the way i want to resolve this.

Can someone explain to me what mistake i'm making here?

I have been looking and trying a lot of code but with no success.

I found this post [Preventing Links before jQuery is Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811513/preventing-links-before-jquery-is-loaded)
but i don't know if this has anything to do with my problem because i only have it with one link.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your html is created by custom web control, you might need use `live()` or `on()`  for JQuery 1.7 and above to bind your click event.

For example:

```
$("body").delegate("a","click", function () {
        buttonOutsidePageClicked = false;
    });
```

from jquery version 1.7 use this:

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function () {
    buttonOutsidePageClicked = false;
});
```

JQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

View online example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7y7ss/)

Comment: This won't work for me because the click event never get's triggered. Or do I miss something in you answer? What does the live method do? Is it different than $("a").click(function () { ... }); ?

Comment: "Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future." You should use live when your html element is created after jquery is load, by other js. In your case, I not sure you custom web control is creating the element via js? You mention your event never being triggered, which mean your event is not attacthed to the DOM element.

Comment: @ThdK - if you dont understand the code, dont say it wont work. now, the 'live' binding is will work even if the an element will be removed/added to the page, so it actually might fix your problem.

Comment: Ok, sry if you gave up to early. I'll try this. But this is what i just found on jquery documentation: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: Oooh, i Feel so stupid now that i thought this was not going to work! Because it works! But i'll have to take a look at the fact that this method is deprecated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I still didn't find on how to do this with the on() method. $("body").on("click", "a", function () {
 buttonOutsidePageClicked = false;
 });   Is not working for me. Do you have any more hint on this?

Comment: @Thdk I added online example in the answer.

Comment: I modified your answer a bit so it fits better to my original question. I did not want to stop the onbeforeunload event, i only wanted to know if it was triggered by a link on my page or by closing the current browser window. Thanks for your time, You really helped me out here!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You can refactor your code to this:

```
$('a[href]').click(function (event) {
    buttonOutsidePageClicked = false;
});
```

Your answer lies probably in:

> These html is created by a custom web control

They are either hijacking the click event so that jQuery click handlers aren't invoked or using the click event on the inner `<span>` element(s).

You can use firebug or chrome developer tools to look at all event listeners. Make sure that one of them is jQuery.

Comment: Oh yes you're right. This was a left over of trying other code to see if that may respond different or not. I updated it in my question. How can i see all event listeners in firebug?

Comment: When i select my link and open the dom panel is see: click    click() I don't know if this is what mean.